# How to visualize and retrieve data lineage from my database?

Tags: visualization, sql-view

I am looking for a mechanism to build a tool to analyze my database and generate data lineage. I have googled online and found there are some tools to do that (such as https://sqlflow.gudusoft.com/) but I would like to build my own sdk in my project. What would be the basic flow to archieve that and how the tools such as Gudu SQLFlow make that?

A tech flow to visualize database and generate data lineage